# Why does using delegates in c# give a stackoverflowexception

Tags: c#, delegates

When I came across delegates I wrote this really simple program just to practice. when I run it there is a stackoverflowexception. so if anyone can tell me what is wrong with this piece of code please do cause I have wasted a lot of time on trying to make it work but couldn't.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
public delegate void click();
class test
{
    public click flare;
    public double length;
    public double Length
    {
        get
        {
            return Length;
        }
        set
        {
            Length = value;
            flare();
        }
    }
}
class glance
{
    public glance(ref test a)
    {
        a.flare = blank;
    }
    public void blank()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is blank");
    }
}
class Program
{enter code here
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        test know = new test();
        glance x = new glance(ref know);
        know.Length = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with delegates. You are calling setter method inside of setter in `Lenght` property and that causes the exception.Use the backing field you created for your property:

```
public double Length
{
    get
    {
        return length;
    }
    set
    {
        length = value;
        flare();
    }
}
```